# Entity Framework DB context often used

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework in the Code-First approach in my application. However, I am working on my entities a lot. In fact all the usage of the application is a constant adding, updating and deleting entities. In all of the tutorials and questions, context is used like that:

```
using (var ctx = new MyDBEntities())
{
    //Operations
}
```

It also says that you should not create one context on the beginning and use the same one during all app's lifetime. Although I know it is important to close the connection after operation, I think that constant creating of new context just to update one row and then leaving it is neither a god solution. I am accessing my database very often (also reading) what increases time and memory (GarbageCollector do not delete them immediately) consumption.

Therefore I would like to ask you for your opinion. What should I do to make it more efficient?

Comment: Although it wont make much difference. Entity framework isn't made for rapid usage with lots of data. instead i recommend you use `Dapper`

Comment: *new context just to update one row* No, but to commit a unit of work: yes.

Comment: @GertArnold, what unit do you exactly mean? I need to update single things usually.

Comment: Then that's your unit of work. Generally you won't call `SaveChanges` twice on the same context.

Comment: Can I first download and cache all the data from DB, make some operations, and then save it all once?

Comment: Is it premature optimization? Are there demonstrated performance problems?

Comment: @SqlACID, no concrete problems. Its just a hypothetical question for now on.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR : It depends.

I wouldn't worry about repeated connection opens and closes, connection pooling will offset any issues there. I think some of the comments hit on some points, if you have a block of work to do, some inserts, some updates, etc, all related, I would do them all under one context. If it's all unrelated, each event handler should have it's own context.

EF can be quite a good performer, I wouldn't use it to load terabytes of data, but for moderate volume it's fine. Make sure your database schema supports your lookups with proper indexing, that will probably go a longer way than anything you could do in the application. Monitor the sql server using profiler, make sure you're using reasonable table sizes, and see what is taking the longest, focus there.